# R-Cassandra connection with RJDBC

Tags: r, databases

I am trying to connect with cassandra in R using [RJDBC](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RJDBC/index.html). When I execute

```
casscon <- dbConnect(cassdrv, "jdbc:cassandra://ipaddrs:9160/demodb")
```

I am getting

```
Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],
: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
```

I can't figure out the problem. I need a solution for this.